# error on execute import django in python3 shell and script

Tags: django, import, virtualenv

when i want do an `import django` i get an error

ubuntu 18.04 with a reverse proxy (nginx) and uwsgi (mode emperor actived) in virtual env with python 3.6.3 and latest django 2.2.5

**test.py:**

```py
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testproject.settings")
import django

print("test")'
```

when i run python3 test.py i get :

```
(venv) :~/testproject/testproject/testproject$ python3.6 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.http import HttpResponse
  File "/home/lukas/testproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "/home/lukas/testproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 4, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 140, in <module>
    import threading
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 7, in <module>
    from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/home/lukas/testproject/venv/lib/python3.6/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/home/lukas/testproject/venv/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "/home/lukas/testproject/testproject/testproject/token.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
  File "/home/lukas/testproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.apps import apps as django_apps
  File "/home/lukas/testproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .registry import apps
  File "/home/lukas/testproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 426, in <module>
    apps = Apps(installed_apps=None)
  File "/home/lukas/testproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.ready_event = threading.Event()
AttributeError: module 'threading' has no attribute 'Event'
```

i have the same error on python3 shell when i do `import django` whereas django have been installed with pip3 install and production mode is ok and developement mode with runserver is ok too.

can you help me, i m lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have, by any chance, a `token` module in you django project?

As the python path is modified to prefer local modules rather than other pre-defined modules, the `from token import *` instruction will import from your module instead of the python lib one.

Try renaming your local modules to avoid collision with builtin python modules.

Comment: Oh !!! thank you very much it's working now, i have changed token name's by tokens and every thing is ok now :)